# Laravel 4 - custom 404 error handling only for missing pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4.1 I want to redirect the user to my customised 404 page if the page is not exists. That's easy because I already have this:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Redirect::to('error404', 303)->with(array('error' => array('url' => Request::url())));
}
```

But the problem is that if any linked file (image, js, css, etc.) is missing on the page I don't get 404 error for that file, but this is showing on console:

`Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "...`

So **the question is**: How can I drop 404 only if a page is missing and leave the default error handling for the rest (images, other files, etc.)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Maybe* if you pass `404` as status code, which means the page wasn't found, instead of `303` which just means you're redirecting, the browser might understand it and work properly.

Comment: No. It has to be 303 as it's a redirecting. If I change it to 404 it throws this: "Error in exception handler: The HTTP status code is not a redirect ("404" given)."

Comment: It should really return 404 though, no? Since that's what it is about? Maybe making the view and returning 404 inside `App::missing` as you do in the `error404` route would be the right call.

Comment: No. I want 404 error only if anything is missing but not webpage. If a page is missing it should redirect to a custom error page (what it does currently).

Comment: You can display the custom error page AND send a 404 status code. This would probably give you the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You could not redirect to a different URL, but still display a custom page for 404 errors and send the `HTTP 404 Status Code`, directly inside `App::missing`, like this:

```
App::missing(function() {
    return Response::make(View::make('error404'), 404);
});
```

This displays the correct view when a page is loaded but forces the browser to throw an error when trying to load a resource, because of the `HTTP 404 Status Code`.

On Chrome 35, I get this error on the console when trying to load an image in an `img` tag:

```
GET http://testing.app:8000/test 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: The issue is that the custom error page has got a controller with some logics. If I make a view directly in the `missing()` then its controller won't execute. Am I wrong?

Comment: Copy the logic to `App::missing` then.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see what the `Request` wants in the `App::missing` method. Not sure if this would work right out of the box, but it's a start.

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    if( Request::format() == 'text/html' )
        return Redirect::to('error404', 303)->with(array('error' => array('url' => Request::url())));
}
```

## Edit

Since the code above doesn't do what you want, I revised it to something else. It feels like a hack and I would not recommend using it in production; I would recommend looking for a better way to do this, but I think this will work. (It does for me)

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    $uri = Request::getRequestUri();
    $ext = explode(".", $uri);

    if( preg_match("/(jpg|gif|png|tif)/", end($ext)) !== 1 )
        return Redirect::to('error404', 303)->with(array('error' => array('url' => Request::url())));
});
```

Part of the reason this is difficult to do is because the application doesn't know what a request string really *should* return. For example, a request uri of `/images/FJB3cB09` could possibly be an image. A uri of `/images/my-profile.jpg` doesn't necessarily have to return a JPEG image. It can't know what the content type is until after it reads the contents of the file; if there's no file found, then you can't accurately tell what you were trying to access. Make sense?

Comment: The Request::format() is 'html' if I "dd()" it and not "text/html". But doesn't matter because it doesn't work. If I try to open eg. http://dev.local/images/pic.png it will be the same... I mean same "html" response and Laravel runs the custom 404. Also if I open a page which is exists but it contains missing image links I get the same error on console like I mentioned in my original question.

Comment: You could try something like this using `Request::header('Accept')`, but I doubt it would be slightly reliable.

Comment: @Goldentoa11 Yes, it works, thanks and I totally agreed, you are right that it seems like a bit hack... I'll wait a bit for another answers and if there won't be better, I'll accept your one as a solution.