# Laravel on nginx. Loading errors problems

Tags: php, apache, laravel, nginx

How i find out that error pages like 404 and all other errors are perfectly working on apache but once it is on nginx its getting errors... maybe my server is missing some php extensions or something else?

my code:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
return View::make('404');
}
```

error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to a member function getAction() on a non-object
```

Comment: Why did you create your question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122291/laravel-error-with-404-page

Comment: Because it was not able to delete. So thats why i created new one with different title to describe problem more in details

Comment: Then just edit the previous.

Comment: its my fault. i was getting error by changing title. Please dont go off-topic. But i still need at least some tips how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look on app>start>gloabl.php and replace the code

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
Log::error($exception);
});
```

with

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
Log::error($exception);
switch ($code)
{
    case 404:
        return Response::view('error', array(), 404);

    case 500:
        return Response::view('error', array(), 500);

    default:
        return Response::view('error', array(), $code);
}

});
```

This works fine on my nginx

Comment: Thanks, now it is working without error like was before. I have a question about blade templating. Is it possible to use it in error page? because i am getting problems now with it

Comment: yes you can use blade templates in the error page